# Interpreting coefficients from Logistic Regression from R

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

All,

I ran a logistic Regression on a set of variables both categorical and continuous with a binary event as dependent variable.

Now post modelling, I observe a set of categorical variables showing negative sign which I presume is to understand that if that categorical variable occurs high number of times then the probability of the dependent variable occurring is low.

But when I see the % of occurrence of that independent variable I see the reverse trend happening. hence the result seems to be counter intuitive. Any reason why this could happen. I have tried explaining below with a pseudo example.

Dependent Variable - E
Predictors:
   1. Categorical Var - Cat1 with 2 levels (0,1)
   2. Continuous Var  - Con1
   3. Categorical Var - Cat2 with 2 levels (0,1)
Post Modelling:
Say all are significant and the coefficients are like below,
Cat1 - (-0.6)
Con1-  (0.3)
Cat2 - (-0.4)

But when I calculate the % of occurrence of Event E on Cat 1, I observe that the % of occurence is high when Cat1 is 1, which I think is counter intuitive.

Pls help in understanding this.

Comment: What is the intercept value? If it is high enough a beta coefficient of -0.6 could still result in a high probability of occurrence.

Comment: it is -1.2,intercept also being negative then does it further deepens the negativity of the categorical variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coefficients of logistic regression are not directly related to the chage of probability of the event, rather it's a relative measure of the change in the **odds** of the event. [This article](https://medium.com/ro-data-team-blog/interpret-the-impact-size-with-logistic-regression-coefficients-5eec21baaac8) has detailed derivation of how to interpret the coefficients of logistic regression. In your context, the coefficient for CAT1 is -0.6 means p(E|CAT1 = 1) < p(E|CAT1 = 0) and it's not related to exactly how big p(E|CAT1 = 1) is.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, what I had understood by now resonates and has been well documented